# Custom APIPlatform Filter array parameter

Tags: php, api-platform.com

Most of my filters allow an array to be passed.  But not my custom filter, the attributes property in this image.

[image]

in getFilterDescription(), I'm returning the following:

```php
            [
                'attributes' => [
                    'property' => 'attributes',
                    'type' => 'array',
                    'required' => false,
                ],
            ];
```

and various hacks, like making the type array[string], or making the property name attributes[], but it keeps coming back prompting for a string and not an array.

I'm guessing this is a simple configuration issue, but I'm stuck.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The "is_collection" property must be set to true.

```php
                sprintf('%s', $propertyName) => [
                    'property' => $propertyName . '[]',
                    'type' => 'string',
                    'is_collection' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                ],
```